# Possible to extend methods of Array in ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array of instances of e.g. class Result, I want to join names of results rather than results with a ',' like below:

```
@results=[result1, result2...]
results.join(", ") do |r|
   r.name
end
```

results.join method should be an extensino methods of Array, I want it available to all arrays in my program.

Possible?

Comment: `#join` is *already* an array method... what are you asking for exactly?

Comment: Why should it be available to all arrays if it only works on arrays of objects that respond to "name"? Besides, you can already collect or map and get the same effect without polluting a general-purpose class with message-specific functionality. Yes, it's possible.

Comment: Yes, join is already a method of array, what I want is the join which can take a block. like def join(delim) { array.map {|x| yield(x) }.join(delim)}

Comment: The code you posted doesn't even work because `join` does not take a block.  You need to use `collect` and then `join`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

```
class Array
  def join_names
    collect(&:name).join(", ")
  end
end
```

But this makes it more likely that you code will have namespace collisions with other libraries that add methods to the Array class.

Comment: Thanks. What I want should be like this, which means I want to override/overload? the existing join function of Array, possible and any problem?

    class Array
      def join(delim)
        if block_given?
          self.map { |item| yield(item) }.join(delim)
        else
          self.join(delim)
        end
      end
    end

Comment: Overriding the built-in function isn't a good idea. Extend Array and define a new method, like `join_names`, as in the answer here.